# IF Checkbox in cell B OR cell C is FALSE, user can't choose data from dropdown in cell A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to prevent user from choosing data from the dropdown inside cell A if checkbox in cell B OR cell C is FALSE.

Even better, if it's possible to not even show the dropdown menu in cell A if checkboxes in B OR C are FALSE.

Dropdown would be disabled by default when B or C are FALSE (also default) and would show up when B OR C would be ticked and changed to TRUE.

Columns B and C are FALSE by default (unchecked actual checkbox).

Is it possible to make this in Google Spreadsheets?

[image: When Checkboxes B OR C are FALSE, there is no dropdown]

[image: When Checkbox B OR C are TRUE, the dropdown shows]

Comment: Are the columns B/C NULL by default then user will input True/false? How is the user inputting the value on cell B/C? Is it an actual checkbox or also a dropdown with True or False as options or is it being typed manually? Also is dropdown enabled by default and only changes once changed to false? If possible share screenshots, sample sheet so we can picture the idea.

Comment: Hey Dan, I've edited my original question according to your suggestions, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using apps script:

[image]

Using app script try the following code. This uses onEdit trigger which runs everytime you edit a cell. It then checks the condition -> if cell B and cell C are both true only then it will show the dropdown list on cell A, if changed to false it will be removed again.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var sh = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
  var rngRow = rng.getRow();
  var rngCol = rng.getColumn();

  var options = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OPTIONS").getRange("A2:A") //set sheetname and cell range where the options are coming from
  var dropdownCell = sh.getRange(rngRow, 1);

  var otherCol = sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' ? rngCol == 2 ? 3 : 2 : '';
  var [cell, otherCell] = sh.getRangeList([`R${rngRow}C${rngCol}`, `R${rngRow}C${otherCol}`])
    .getRanges().map(range => range.getValue());

  if (rngCol == 2 || rngCol == 3) {
    if (cell && otherCell) {
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(options)
        .build();
      dropdownCell.setDataValidation(rule);
    } else {
      dropdownCell.setDataValidation(null);
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

The options for data validation are coming from the other tab/sheet "**OPTIONS**", starting on row 2.

[image]

Comment: Wow, haven't seen that before. I really need to learn Javascript so badly. :( I will try that option as well, thank you. <3

Comment: I'm getting thiss error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:2

Comment: @MountainSpring Hi, thank you for replying. That is because you can't run the function onEdit directly. It automatically runs when you make changes to a value in a spreadsheet. Since the value (e) is only being created when you make edits and it is used as the input in the function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite. Just paste the code in the script editor and save it. Then try playing around with the checkboxes.

Comment: Also put the dropdown list in another tab OPTIONS, otherwise if you want to keep it in your main sheet or change the sheet name you can edit  on the line var options in the code. I have it in the comment in the codes where you will edit. Let me know if this resolves your issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a toy example of how to do this without Apps Script. Obviously you would need to modify to suit your requirements.

In A1, switch on 'List from a range' data validation, and set the range to 'D1:G1'. In B1 & C1, add tick boxes. In D1, enter the following formula:

```
=if(or(B1,C1),{"A","B","C","D"},)
```

So whenever B1 or C1 is ticked, an array literal is expanded into D1:G1, and the contents of these cells populate the data validation list for A1. When neither is ticked, D1 is null and no validation list is available. Obviously the validation range doesn't need to be in D1; anywhere (even another sheet) will work provided you point the data validation in A1 to the right range.

Comment: This looks like nice and simple solution but the formula returns #ERROR! - Formula parse error on Google Spreadsheets. Couldn't debug why this is happening. :(

Comment: Might be related to your spreadsheet locale as this is working fine at my end... Are you based somewhere which uses commas as the decimal separator? If so the formula in D1 would need to be changed to (I think) =if(or(B1;C1);{"A"\"B"\"C"\"D"};)

Comment: And you were right, works like a charm now, thanks a lot. <3

Comment: Really nice, simple solution. Formulas strain much less a sheet and there is no delay as when using scripts. Kudos.